# how to deploy the web application/static web project in NGINX

Tags: git, nginx, jenkins

we have a static project comprising of js,html ,images. How to deploy it in NGINX web server.

I want to know how a web application or any application will be deployed to Nginx

are the below options will work out?

1.Do we need to create  a project specific folder  under nginx home directory and serving them from home directory, but  how the old files of home directory will be replaced with git repository latest files

2.serving from  a separate file system, from the file system WAR will be read by NGINX.

3.Do we need to configure NGINX such that it consumes the WAR file from the JENKINS

or is there any other procedure to deploy the project on NGINX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Need to add the  project folder under  Nginx/html/<>

2.Just check in to Git will do the rest,jenkins will take the latest changes